# ScrollMagic not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

In all browsers, excluding IE11, this jQuery works to add a new class `running` to elements with the class `paused` upon scrolling to the trigger element.

The trigger element is set on a div. As in Firefox, Safari and Chrome it adds the class. But it IE11, it doesn't seem to pickup on the trigger.

Is this possibly an issue with IE11 and jQuery .ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var scene1 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger1"})
                        .setClassToggle(".svg1 .paused", "running")
                        .addTo(controller);
        var scene3 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger3"})
                        .setClassToggle(".svg3 .paused", "running")
                        .addTo(controller);

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 991) {

        var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger5"})
                        .setClassToggle(".svg2 .paused", "running")
                        .addTo(controller);

        var scene4 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger6"})
                        .setClassToggle(".svg4 .paused", "running")
                        .addTo(controller);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {

    var scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger2"})
                    .setClassToggle(".svg2 .paused", "running")
                    .addTo(controller);

    var scene4 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger4"})
                    .setClassToggle(".svg4 .paused", "running")
                    .addTo(controller);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer, without a solution.

You cannot add a class to an SVG in IE11 using jQuery/JavaScript. Therefore, ScrollMagic would work in IE11 if it was a PNG/JPEG etc, but not an SVG.